# ¿Cómo puedo retornar un único valor al mapear un objeto y dentro de éste objeto un array?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy practicando la lectura de archivos en Node.js y tengo un inconveniente, ya que el input está es un archivo .txt y éste lo leo y retorno su contenido para poder trabajarlo.

Lo que trata este ejercicio es que debo retornar el nombre y las veces que se repite con otro nombre el día y la misma hora

El input o contenido dentro del .txt es el siguiente

```
RENE=MO10:00-12:00,TU10:00-12:00,TH01:00-03:00,SA14:00-18:00,SU20:00-21:00
ASTRID=MO10:00-12:00,TH12:00-14:00,SU20:00-21:00
ANDRES=MO10:00-12:00,TH12:00-14:00,SU20:00-21:00
```

Y el output que espero es el siguiente

```
ASTRID-RENE: 2
ASTRID-ANDRES: 3
RENE-ANDRES: 2
```

Y el problema que tengo actualmente es que no sé como poder hacer para retornar el output esperado

Este es mi código javascript

```
const employeesData = data();

const employees = employeesData.split(/\r?\n|\r|\n/g);

const employeesSchedule = employees.map((employee) => {
    const [name, schedule] = employee.split('=');
    return { name, schedule };
});

const employeesScheduleDays = employeesSchedule.map((employee) => {
    const { name, schedule } = employee;
    const days = schedule.split(',').map((day) => day.substring(0, 2));
    const hours = schedule.split(',').map((day) => day.substring(2));
    return { name, days, hours };
});
console.log(employeesScheduleDays);
```

Y el console.log que obtengo es el siguiente y hasta ahí pude desarrollar por lo que necesito de su ayuda

```
[
  {
    name: 'RENE',
    days: [ 'MO', 'TU', 'TH', 'SA', 'SU' ],
    hours: [
      '10:00-12:00',
      '10:00-12:00',
      '01:00-03:00',
      '14:00-18:00',
      '20:00-21:00'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'ASTRID',
    days: [ 'MO', 'TH', 'SU' ],
    hours: [ '10:00-12:00', '12:00-14:00', '20:00-21:00' ]
  },
  {
    name: 'ANDRES',
    days: [ 'MO', 'TH', 'SU' ],
    hours: [ '10:00-12:00', '12:00-14:00', '20:00-21:00' ]
  },
  {
    name: 'DAVID',
    days: [ 'MO', 'TU', 'TH', 'SA', 'SU' ],
    hours: [
      '10:15-12:00',
      '10:00-12:00',
      '13:00-13:15',
      '14:00-18:00',
      '20:00-21:00'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'MARIA',
    days: [ 'MO', 'TH', 'SU' ],
    hours: [ '10:00-12:00', '12:00-14:00', '20:00-21:00' ]
  },
  {
    name: 'FERNANDA',
    days: [ 'MO', 'TH', 'SU' ],
    hours: [ '10:00-12:00', '12:00-14:00', '20:00-21:00' ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy interesante el ejercicio al igual que la solución, se puede decir que me divertí dando la respuesta :)

```javascript
let output = {};

// recorrer lista de empleados
for (let i = 0; i < employeesScheduleDays.length; i++) {
  let employee = employeesScheduleDays[i];

  // recorrer empleados a comparar con él
  for (let j = i + 1; j < employeesScheduleDays.length; j++) {
    let partner = employeesScheduleDays[j];
    let coincidences = 0;

    // recorrer días y horas
    for (let x = 0; x < employee.days.length; x++) {
      let day = employee.days[x];
      let hour = employee.hours[x];
      // al coincidir dia y hora de ambos empleados (employee y partner)
      if (partner.days.includes(day) && partner.hours.includes(hour)) {
        coincidences ++;
      }
    }

    output[employee.name + "-" + partner.name] = coincidences;
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Si fue un ejercicio interesante jejeje te agradezco mucho tu solución ya que si llega al output esperado, eres un crack